# C# version of Java Runnable? (delegate?)

Tags: c#, delegates, first-class-functions

I could not find a direct answer to this question yet in SO. Is there a predefined delegate with `void (void)` signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) has the signature you're looking for. However, it doesn't mean the same thing as Runnable does: Runnable generally indicates that the run() method is intended to be run on a Thread, while Action makes no indication. For that you'd want [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx), which has the same signature, and does make that indication.

If all you need is a delegate with no parameters, `Action` is what you want. If you're dealing with threads and need to indicate the start method, use `ThreadStart`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. C# handles threads differently to Java. In Java, the Runnable interface is an alternative to subclassing Thread, but you still have to create a new Thread object, passing the Runnable to a constructor.

Rather than subclassing the `Thread` class, you simply create a new `System.Threading.Thread` object and pass it a `ThreadStart` delegate (this is the function where you do the work). ThreadStart is the exact C# equivalent to Java's Runnable.

However, the `Action` delegate has the `void` parameters you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

The Action delegate is a void with no parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

There are also other signatures with up to 16 parameters.