# C# using something similar to Java Handler?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, runnable

In Java, there is a way where you set a Handler and a Runnable so you can return from a function and get that Runnable thing to run later.

What is the equivalent of this tasks in C#?

```
private Runnable mShowContentRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
};

private void obtainData() {

    mainActivity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mShowContentRunnable, 375);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the code that you would use in Java?

Comment: I've edited your question -- I'm pretty sure the last line of your question is *supposed* to read as I've made it.

Comment: Read async/await. When you understand it, I am sure you will love it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: This is part of the Android API, not part of the Java language. If you're asking about `Runnable`, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078736/c-sharp-version-of-java-runnable-delegate

Comment: Did you do any research into how to delay execution of an operation using tasks in C#?  What did you find?  What problems did you have implementing the solutions you found?